# QuestDB cloud ILP connection error: Failed to read authentication challenge (timed out?): Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)

Tags: questdb, influx-line-protocol

I am following the code example from QuestDB and migrating my data from InfluxDB. I have files exported in ILP format, so I read and send them one by one using:

```
    try:
        with Sender(host, port, auth=auth, tls=True, auto_flush=4096) as sender:
            with open(in_file, "r") as input:
                lines = input.readlines()

           
                for index, line in enumerate(lines):
                    table, symbols, columns, timestamp_nano = read_line(line, index)
                    sender.row(table, symbols=symbols, columns=columns, at=timestamp_nano)

    except IngressError as e:
        sys.stderr.write(f"Fail: {e}\n")
```

But sometimes after sending many files successfully, my script fails to connect with

```
Failed to read authentication challenge (timed out?): Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)
```

What does error 11 mean? Is is the auth failure or network?

Comment: Is the resource pingable?  If it pings its an auth issue, if it doesn't ping its a hardware one.

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure since it happens in the middle of the run and lasts for 10 minutes. I assume since I run it on the cloud infra the network should not be down for 10 mins every day.

Comment: what QuestDB version do you use? There was ILP authentication fix in 7.3.3: https://github.com/questdb/questdb/pull/3817
this could lead to a timeout during authentication.

Comment: Oh you know if it is running for 10 minutes then seems to disappear, perhaps you have a timeout that is being breached and it drops the connection?

Comment: I think you're right it's a timeout, if I increase the connection timeout time on the client it goes away, thank you.